# Was Hitler Jewish?

Tags: history, adolf-hitler

What evidence is there to show conclusively that Hitler was or was not Jewish or had Jewish ancestry even if he was not a practicing Jew?

Comment: Straight dope on this issue: http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/797/was-hitler-part-jewish

Comment: I've heard that the anti-semitic Vladmir Zhirinovsky is of partially Jewish descent.

Comment: To fund the ironic claim, that the racist mass murderer of Jews might have been partly a Jew himself, you first have to buy the racist definition of 'Jews', made by the Nazis, which wasn't scientific. Only if you ignore the facts, and propagate the ideology further, you can claim that he `was Jewish`. And how would somebody prove his ancestries 3000 to 4000 years back? And even if you could find a grandfather - what would it show? The question is only relevant for racists. To be a Jew is a religion, and there is no Jewish gen, nor a Jewish nation.

Comment: @uu: I never said that it was ironic. I merely wondered whether that was responsible for his anti-jewish philosophy.

Comment: To make notifications work, you have to cite at least 3 characters, afaik, so @uu doesn't reach me, try @use instead. How do you define ancestry? If you calculate one generation with 30 years, and count your or somebodies ancestry back 2000 years, you get 66 generations. 2^62 is already 4 611 686 018 427 387 904, but of course not all of them were distinct. Now imagine to go back to the time of the first jews, which is about 4000 years back. How big are the chances to not have Jewish ancestries?

Comment: How to define "Jewish", according to the definition used by Jews, the one used by Nazis, other?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It's not known with full certainty who Hitler's father's father was (although George Hiedler is the generally accepted one). For a list of theories on the matter, see the [Wikipedia article about Alois Hitler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alois_Hitler#Biological_father).

Since Hitler's father's mother got pregnant while allegedly working for a Jewish family it has been claimed that the father is actually the 19-year old son of this Jewish family. That would make Adolf Hitler one quarter Jewish according to the race laws in Nazi Germany.

However, there is not a smidgen of evidence for this theory. It has become popular because of the immense potential for irony, should it be true. But it probably isn't.

Source: Frank McDonough, *Hitler and the rise of the Nazi Party*, Pearson Education, 2003, p. 20.

Comment: *It has become popular because of the immense potential for irony, should it be true.* -- I think it has become popular because it pins the holocaust on the Jews.

Comment: But even if it was true, that would not pin the Holocaust on the Jews. Hitler would likely have been unaware of his Jewish heritage, and not even seen as a Jew in the matrilinear traditional view. And one person is not "the Jews". So that makes absolutely no sense whatsoever in three different ways.

Comment: Under their school of thought, though, wouldn't his lack of awareness be an artifact of his inferiority from simply being Jewish? (Disclaimer: I don't actually feel that way, just using their line of reasoning.)

Comment: @Lennart, I am not sure you understand how anti-semitism, or bigotry or racism for that matters works.  Making logical sense is the least of it.  The question remains, if it is clear that Hitler was not Jewish, why is this meme so popular? None of the answers here address that.  My suggestion is that the question allows antisemites to absolve Germany of the Holocaust and pin it on the Jews, much like the Jews and Judas were blamed for killing Christ, a Jew.  It's another example of Jewish evil. Even Hitler was Jewish. Here is a book at Amazon - read just the description: http://amzn.to/kTyk8S

Comment: @Jerry: No, that question does not remain, it has been answered. It's so popular because if it was true, it would be the biggest "ooh isn't that ironic" of humankind. Your answer is assuming that anyone going "Hitler was part Jewish" is stupid and anti-semitic. But those who want an excuse for the holocaust goes a much easier way: Denying it ever happened. That means there is nothing to pin on anyone. But pinning it on Jews via a Jewish Hitler means you must admit it happened. And then the Jewish evil is turned...against Jews? That doesn't fit with the conspiracy. So no. Doens't work.

Comment: You state as fact that Hitler's father's mother worked for a Jewish family. According to my <strike>extensive research</strike> few minutes of Googling, this is itself unlikely, since the Jews had been expelled from that part of Austria in the 15th century. The whole thing may well have been invented by Hans Frank.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yeah, because nobody moved anywhere after the 15th century. ;-) It's not really relevant, though, since the idea that Maria Shicklgruber got pregnant by the son in the household has no evidence, so the existence or not of the Frankenbergers aren't really relevant.

Comment: The fact that the existence of the Frankenbergers is uncertain adds weight to the conclusion. I'm not arguing the conclusion, merely that you've stated as a fact something that appears to be far from certain. I suggest that your answer would be improved by changing "while working for a Jewish family" to something like "while allegedly working for a Jewish family".

Comment: @KeithThompson Fair enough, it doesn't hurt.

Comment: Jewish lineage is determined along matriarchal lines, so the father isn't as important as the mother. This was certainly the case in German race laws. The rumour is that his grandmother was part Jewish, which'd make him Jewish according to his own laws.

Comment: @jwenting No, that was certainly not the case with the German Race laws. Racism in general, and Nazism in particular is based on the idea that mixing races "defiles" the blood. If it's a mother or a father makes no difference. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mischling_Test

Comment: @KeithThompson very strange argument: "since the Jews had been expelled from that part of Austria in the 15th century."  And from what I have found using google is that from 1867 on, Jews would become full citizens of the Austrian-Hungarian empire allowing them to "settle freely" as any other citizen.  There's a lot of time between being chased away in the 15th century and moving back more than 400 years later.  But maybe your post was ironic, and I did not get it?? :|

Comment: @KlausN My post was based on a quick Google search that I did almost 7 years ago. My comment wasn't meant to be ironic. It was merely incomplete (as I acknowledged).

Answer (score 6):

**Who is a Jew?**

> The definition of who is a Jew varies according to whether it is being considered by Jews based on normative religious statutes, self-identification, or by non-Jews for other reasons. Because Jewish identity can include characteristics of an ethnicity, a religion, and citizenship, the definition of who is a Jew has varied, depending on whether a religious, sociological, or ethnic aspect was being considered.
>   —[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Who_is_a_Jew%3F)

- **Genome-wise**: He surely shared genome with the Jewish population. We all come from a [common ancestor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_descent). Furthermore, [there is no such thing as a Jewish race](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/498027/jewish/Are-Jews-a-Race.htm), so the question does not make much sense when seen from this point of view. Everybody is related to Jews.
- **Religion-wise**: He had a Christian family and education:

  [image: Hitler's baptism certificate]
  <sub>(source: [wikimedia.org](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e0/Hitler_Baptism_Certificate0002.jpg))</sub>
- **Nationality-wise**: He was [Austrian](http://www.historylearningsite.co.uk/adolf-hitler.htm) first, and then German. There is no evidence or historical doubt that his [nationality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationality) was other then Austrian/German.

  [image: House where Hitler was born]
- **Self-identification-wise**: He didn't really like Jews, so I doubt he self-defined as one:

  > "*If I am ever really in power, the destruction of the Jews will be my first and most important job. As soon as I have power, I shall have gallows after gallows erected, for example, in Munich on the Marienplatz-as many of them as traffic allows. Then the Jews will be hanged one after another, and they will stay hanging until they stink. They will stay hanging as long as hygienically possible. As soon as they are untied, then the next group will follow and that will continue until the last Jew in Munich is exterminated. Exactly the same procedure will be followed in other cities until Germany is cleansed of the last Jew!*"
  >   —[Adolf Hitler](http://www.ess.uwe.ac.uk/genocide/statements.htm)
- **According to Nazi laws**: unlikely (but the laws seem recursive to me, so it's really hard to say). I doubt that any German tribunal would have declared him a Jew in those times. For more information see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mischling_Test).

  [image: Definition of Jew]

Comment: The baptism certificate can be seen [here](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Hitler_Baptism_Certificate0002.jpg). But it must be fake - everyone knows Hitler was born in Kenya! :)

Comment: I'm not trying to stalk the diamond mods, but I don't think this is a good answer. For "genome-wise", you state we all share a common ancestor, but you don't provide any evidence that the last common ancestor was Jewish. For "Nationality-wise", you don't expand upon the brief mention of nationality and Jewishness in the introductory paragraph, and how being Austrian or German is relevant.

Comment: For "self-identification-wise": the page you link to cites holocaust denier David Irving for a separate quote without any warnings about the reliability of his work. The quote that you supply was apparently from a book by John Toland - I was initally a bit concerned, because Toland seems to be a Pearl Harbor truther, but his book receives good ratings at amazon.com. (One of the Amazon.com reviews suggests that Toland suggests Hitler may have Jewish blood in him, BTW)

Comment: @Andrew: I've updated the answer to address your concerns, I hope it's clearer now. Regarding the citation, I used it because it was to-the-point. The other source I was looking at was the Mein Kampf, but I would have needed to cite much longer pieces of it as the tone is less direct.

Comment: For "According to Nazi laws", you don't provide any plain text citations, just a picture of a primary source. I'm not meaning to be rhetorical, but is that enough to back up your claims, especially if a person reading your answer is blind or visually impaired?

Comment: "Furthermore, there is no such thing as a Jew race" ... much as I'd like to disagree with Hitler, if ashkenazi Jews have a higher incidence of Tay-Sachs than non-ashkenazi-Jewish-Europeans, then I can't rule out a "Jew race" as a total fiction.

Comment: Edited - again. Anything else? :-)

Comment: @Andrew: you can have an African Jew, an Asian Jew etc etc... it's not a race.

Comment: @Sklivvz: Are you prepared to back up your assertion there's no such thing as a Jewish race with a citation?

Comment: @Andrew: done..

Comment: @Sklivvz: How reliable is that citation? (PS: I wasn't the person who downvoted you)

Comment: Chimpanzees and human beings "all come from a common ancestor."   So do whales and hippopotamuses. Does this mean it is impossible to distinguish between a chimpanzee and a human being, or a whale and a hippo, to say they have no genetic differences?  I don't know if Ashkenazi Jews can be properly called a "race", since obscurantists have twisted that word to require a strenuous level of difference, but A. Jews are certainly inbred to a point that no geneticist would confuse them with a European -- they have a long-lived Semitic DNA signature, they are certainly a population unto themselves.

Comment: So -1 for empty cliches.

Comment: @Andrew: well it's good enough for the Jews themselves which surely are authoritative when speaking about the definition of their own community, so it's good enough for me.

Comment: @Billare: Ashkenazi Jews are not the same thing as the whole community of Jews. Furthermore your point really makes no sense. Surely there are differences between any two individuals that are not twins. That doesn't make them two separate races. Finally, please moderate your tone. Not providing an answer and calling other people's work an "empty cliche" for a single point on which you disagree *could* be considered trolling by a less nice moderator...

Comment: @Sklivvz Ashkenazi Jews, "European" Jews, are obviously the only sub-population of Jews relevant to
this question. Are you arguing otherwise? And my point makes perfect sense. Consider a
population characterized by DNA made of 6-digit binary string, with each bit having equal
probability of being 0 or 1; 001000 and 101010 would be members. In a large, randomly mating
population, the progeny of one mating of individuals differs from *every* another mating of
individuals in an average 3 places, the same as the average genetic distance between their parents
-- that is the definition of random.

Comment: @Sklivvz (cont'd) Now suppose members of this population with 0s in the first bit started mating exclusively
with another, and those with 1s in their first bit did the same.   Then **Os race** would differ
genetically from each other at 3 - 0.5 = 2.5 bits of DNA, and would differ from the **1s race** at 3
+ 0.5 = 4.5 bits of DNA.   WLOG, vice versa, the same would hold for the **1s race**.

Comment: @Sklivvz (cont'd) Then we can say that the **0s race** is 2.5 - 3 / 3 = 16% more alike each other than they are to an average
member of the population.  **That is the core of the definition of what race, ethnic group, family,
phylum, genus are**: members share more of their DNA with "each other" than they do with other
groups on average; the only difference between the above is that there are different interesting
thresholds to draw.

Comment: @Sklivvz (cont'd) In fact, if you'd studied this, you'd know that this "shared DNA" concept is just as fundamental to biological typology as the
Planck units are to particle physics. Ashkenazi Jews are a "race", an "ethnic group", a "family",
whatever term suits your fashion, because they share more DNA on with each other than they do with the
average member of whatever other group they are being compared to.

Comment: @Billare, write your own answer instead of posting comments. This is not a forum.

Comment: According to the Nazi race laws you were to be regarded as a Jew for the purpose of the law if you have one or more parents that was of the Jewish faith. Hitler would therefore have been jewish in the view of these laws, had his fathers father really been this Jewish young man. Which it wasn't.

Comment: what about not using wikipedia as a primary source :) Pretty comprehensive analysis of what a Jew is otherwise, but no evidence of Hitler's status

Comment: @jwenting: If you read carefully, wikipedia is not used as primary source, but as a further reading source and for definitions. There are 6 non-wikipedia sources cited.

Comment: you use wikipedia as the sole source of information on Nazi race laws (which are the ones that would be used to class Hitler as a Jew at the time). All other categories are secondary to that one, which is the sole test that would be applied at the time.

Comment: @jwenting: the picture included is a primary source. The fact that it appears on wikipedia is not relevant. Furthermore your assertion about the importance is purely subjective. I disagree that the OP asks about Hitler being a Jew according to his laws. The question is more general.

Comment: -1 Please address Billare's criticism in your answer. "There is no such thing" is simply too much of a blanket statement.